# Problemas al copiar base de datos de proyecto en Heroku

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

Estoy intentando copiarme la base de datos de un proyecto que esta en Heroku, le paso el comando que esta en la misma pagina de Heroku para bajarse la base de datos

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL <Nombre_de_la_db_local> --app <Nombre_de_la_app_en_heroku>
```

Y comienza a bajar la DB sin problemas, el error comienza cuando empieza `pg_dump: salvando las definiciones de la base de datos`

y me lanza el siguiente error

```
    pg_restore: [archiver] versión no soportada (1.14) en el encabezado del archivo
pg_dump: extrayendo el contenido de la tabla «public.actividad_economicas»
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:150:25)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:141:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:770:11)
    at Socket._write (net.js:782:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:415:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:305:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:726:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)
    at Socket.onerror (_stream_readable.js:758:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:446:5)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:473:5)
    at internal/streams/destroy.js:50:7
    at Socket._destroy (net.js:663:5)
    at Socket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:38:8)
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:150:17) {
  errno: 'EPIPE',
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

tengo Ruby 2.4.6 y Rails 4.2.8, nota este error no me había pasado antes!

Comment: Se me imagina que debe ser alguna diferencia entre la versión de PostgresSQL que está funcionando en Heroku y la que estás usando localmente. Verifica que sean las mismas.

Comment: En el proyecto de Heroku esta la 11.5 y local tengo 12.1

Comment: Bueno...eso, no tienes las mismas versiones. Es bastante probable que instalando 11.5 localmente resuelva tu problema. Me cuentas como te fue. Saludos

Comment: @AlterLagos Logre solucionar el problema! utilice dpkg -l | grep postgres y me mostró que Postgresql-11 y 12 estaban instalados al mismo tiempo, desinstale, postgresql completamente y lo volví a instalar y funciono me dejo copiar las bases de datos. pero ahora tengo un error Interno con PGAdmin4 cuando intento hacer cualquier consulta a la base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya por fin logre solucionar todo mis problemas! 
1) Tenia Postgresql 11.5 y 12.1 instalados al mismo tiempo (O.S. Ubuntu 18.4.3) así que borre Postgresql por completo (Lo cual fue una mala idea, porque solo tenia que borrar o el 11.5 o el 12.1) Volví a instalar solamente el Postgresql 12.1, 
2) Reinstale PGadmin4 pero al darme problemas con la conexión revise como usuario ROOT quien tocaba el puerto :80 que me estaba fallando lo hice con `netstat -tulpn | grep :80` o también `netstat -ntlp | grep :80`
3) desinstale nginx que me estaba utilizando el puerto :80 y finalice su proceso con `kill -9 495` y listo ya todo bien.